# Custom comparator for a priority queue without defining a nested class

Tags: c++11, comparator, priority-queue, custom-compare

I have a class called getout (no constructor). Within that class I have some private variables that are priority queues. The priority queues are initialized with a custom comparator function that I am supposed to create:

```
priority_queue<tile, vector<tile>, ****insert comparator here***> primary;
```

I understand that custom comparators can be written using a class or struct. However I cannot do it this way (Im sure there's a way). The reason why is within this comparator I use functions pertaining to my class getout. I decided to write my comparator as a regular bool function as follows:

```
class escape{

public:
//grabs row of the tile
int get_row(int index){
    return floor(index/size);
}

//grabs column of the tile
int get_col(int index){
    return index - get_row(index)*size;
}

//stores information about each tile of the grid
struct tile{
    int index;
};

//returns the index provided a row and column
int get_index(int row, int col){
    return row*size + col;
}
//comparator less_than
bool less_than(const tile &t1, const tile &t2)
{
    if(t1.rubble_amount == t2.rubble_amount){
        //return object with lower column value
        if(get_col(t1.index) == get_col(t2.index)){
            return get_row(t1.index) > get_row(t2.index);
        }
        //if column values are same, return object with lower row
        else if(get_col(t1.index) > get_col(t2.index)){
            return true;
        }
    }//if
    return t1.rubble_amount > t2.rubble_amount;
}//comparator less_than

};
```

The functions pertaining to my class I am using are get_row(), get_col(). I do not want to resolve this by making them member variables of my tile structs.

How do I define the comparator of my priority queue that is of the form of a bool function?

Everything is in my class getout.

I have tried:

```
priority_queue<tile, vector<tile>, function<bool(tile, tile)>> primary(less_than);
```

But I am getting an error "Unknown type name less_than". Am I implementing the above code correctly ? Is there another way I can do this?

(all necessary libraries are included)

Thanks!!

Comment: You should add a language tag. I assume C++?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Once you do, it will be much easier to help you. Make sure your code is trimmed down to minimal size that reproduces the issue as written in the link.

Comment: I have provided MCVE

Comment: `class escape:` is not C++.  Please post real C++.

Comment: I know, it is fixed now.

Comment: Your comparator needs access to an `escape` object. You'll need to capture it somewhere, say in a class or in a lambda.